# name of logical negation symbol ¬

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

The instructor of a statistics and probability course uses an odd (to me) symbol for **logical negation**. The symbol is not a tide (~) or an exclamation mark (!) or the bar-over symbol. This symbol looks like the top right hand corner of a rectangle. What is this symbol called?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Could you upload a sketch of this symbol to help us identify it, please? As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: Also, have you already tried [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/)?

Comment: You're looking for `$\neg$`; for more symbols, see [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Comment: @Werner Do I need to load a package to have access to `\neg`?

Comment: @a06e: No, `\neg` is available by default. You can try with [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/2nq8QDrE), which should compile without problem and yield ¬x.

Comment: Ok just tested, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 44):

I have seen that symbol rather frequently and is a popular mathematical notation. AFAIK `~` and `!` are more popular in computer science/engineering, because there is an actual symbol for that on the keyboard. `:)` The symbol is defined in math mode as `\neg`.

Comment: As a character, it’s “¬” U+00AC NOT SIGN, and it’s the standard symbol for negation in logic and mathematics (most recently, as per the ISO 80000-2 standard, which does not even mention other notations for it).

Comment: Actually UK keyboards have the ¬ symbol too. As does the US international keyboard layout (altgr + "\"). So the reason other symbols are more popular is because the normal US layout is more common.